# How can I escape special symbols in scala string at runtime?

Tags: string, scala, escaping, string-literals

Is there a general Scala utility method that converts a string to a string literal? The simple lambda function `"\"" + _ + "\""` only works for strings without any special characters.

For example, the string `\"` (length 2) should be converted to the string `"\\\""` (length 6).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at Apache Common's `StringEscapeUtils` class ([docs here](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)). `escapeJava` should get the job done.

Have a look at [this example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-escape-a-string-for-java.html) to see it in action (in Java).

Answer (score 12):

Wrap the String with 3 quotes to represent it as is..

e.g.
`val str = """ \" """     // str : java.lang.String =  \"`

Comment: That won't help me, I need to generate a string literal at *runtime*.

Comment: ohh.. Then prolly `StringEscapeUtils` as suggested by Malte Schwerhoff should be it.. :)